# Not pass full query string to redirected url in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am creating a htaccess file, I currently have a long url looking like this:

domain.com/file.aspx?id=1000&AE=value1&PL=value2

I want to redirect it to look like:

seconddomain.com/directory/subdirectory/1000

(i.e. just use the value of the ID key passed).

This is what I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+).*$
RewriteRule ^file.aspx$ http://seconddomain.com/directory/subdirectory/%1 [R=301,L]
```

However, what I end up getting is:

http://seconddomain.com/directory/subdirectory/1000?id=1000&AE=value1&PL=value2

i.e. the value of ID gets put in the correct spot -- however, the full query string is appended. I do not have a QSA flag.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the query string is automatically appended if you don't set one yourself, try sticking a `?` at the end of the redirect path to override that and see if that helps

**EDIT**

Just to clarify your code would look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+).*$
RewriteRule ^file.aspx$ http://seconddomain.com/directory/subdirectory/%1? [R=301,L]
```